# Getting number of query executions for a definite period of time

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have an application that uses a single database on MS SQL Server. I need to learn some statistics about application requests to database to analyse it and improve performance.

Basically I need kind of a summary of information that is displayed in **Recent Expensive Queries** in **Activity Monitor** of **SQL Server Management Studio**. The most important thing to know is total number of executions of the query for definite period of time (working time of a heavy function). Please, take into consideration that a query in Activity Monitor looks like that:

```
SELECT [A],[B],[C] FROM [Table] WHERE [ID]=@1
```

so, there are often same query but with different parameter(s).

Please, let me know the options for gathering such data or just share your ideas of "how to". I will learn and try it and write about the results.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I really enjoy the articles that this individual provides

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/14/sql-server-find-most-expensive-queries-using-dmv/

Also, I would make sure that your application has its own SQl Login because it will make things much easier when analyzing data.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all query that now is executing.

```
USE master;

SELECT  st.text,
    r.session_id,
    r.status,
    r.command,
    r.cpu_time,
    r.total_elapsed_time
FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests r
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS st
```

And you can get all 50 last query that are execued

```
SELECT TOP 50
    deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time],
    dest.text AS [Query]
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

And I you suggest that with SQL Server Profiler, Profile your database and save your result in one table in a database and then select all command and group by that to analyzes.

```
Select * 
From
(
    Select 
        Convert(VarChar(Max) , PT.TextData ) As ExecutedCommand ,
        COUNT( RowNumber ) As CommandCount
    From ProfilerTable As PT (nolock)
    Where       
        ( PT.TextData Is Not Null )
        And
        ( PT.EndTime Is Not Null )
    Group By Convert( VarChar( Max ) , PT.TextData )
) As SubQuery
Order By SubQuery.CommandCount Desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Plug the query into SSMS and turn on Query/Include Actual Execution Plan. This will take some getting used to to read, but, in general, look for table scans. A table scan usually means that an index should be present on a join, group by or where clause column.